# how to fix port is already allocated. ERRO[0000] error waiting for container: context canceled?

Tags: python, ubuntu, stack, bots, putty

docker: Error response from daemon: driver failed programming external connectivity on endpoint strange_saha (a45914a6cf94c5829a63acca5e09ae7180953593f275bf3c45e47e641e050f51): Bind for 0.0.0.0:80 failed: port is already allocated. ERRO[0000] error waiting for container: context canceled